# Detect iBeacon signals in iOS during terminated state

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, ibeacon

There are three states for a app

1. Foreground
2. Background
3. Terminated

iBeacons are working perfectly in Foreground and Background and sending notifications to the users.
In case, of terminated state, how can I detect users enter the range of iBeacon and send notification to the user?
I'm writing code in swift.

Comment: There are actually 4 states, foreground, background, suspended and terminated. When the app is terminated, as long as your are "outside" the beacon region you should get relaunched on region entry as long as you have "always" location permission

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually, I have enabled "always location permission" and "location update" background mode, and it's working perfectly on location update. But the thing I want to implement is, How can I detect the signals if the user manually closed the app and enters the range of iBeacon?

Comment: David Young's answer explains how

Answer (score 4):

You may use iBeacon transmissions to auto-launch an app from a terminated state on iOS (either after killing the app or a minute or so after reboot once everything is fully initialized.)  This works for both a "region entry" (at least one beacon being detected after a period where none are detected) or a "region exit" (all beacons matching the region disappearing for > 30 seconds).  Under ideal conditions, auto-launch on beacon detection happens in under one second.

In order for this to work, you must ensure that *ALL* of the following are done:

1. **Call `startMonitoring(region: Region)`** on `LocationManager` with a `CLBeaconRegion` object that matches your beacons.
2. **Start Monitoring in the `didFinishLaunching`** method of the AppDelegate.  If you do not trigger a start to  monitoring before the return of this method, auto-launch won't work.
3. **Obtain "always" location permission** from the user.  If the app does not obtain "always" permission from the user and only gets "when in use" or "just once" location permission, then auto-launch won't work.
4. **Location and Bluetooth must be turned on** in settings.
5. **Wait for Location Services to be ready.**  If you have rebooted the phone, you must wait for a minute or so before location services are fully initialized.  If a beacon appears or disappears before location services are fully initialized, auto-launch won't work right away.
6. **Make sure a region state change happens.** In order to auto-launch upon detecting a beacon, iOS must have previously detected that all beacons matching the `CLBeaconRegion` had disappeared.  In testing, this means that you need to let your app run (it's easiest to do this in the foreground) for at least 30 seconds with no matching beacons in the vicinity to ensure iOS knows it is "outside" the region before testing auto-launch on region entry.  Failure to do this during testing often leads to the wrong conclusion that auto-launch on detection doesn't work.

In order to auto-launch upon not detecting a beacon, you must
similarly make sure that iOS sees at least one beacon before all
beacons disappear.  Understand that it takes time for iOS to
determine that all beacons have disappeared. Under ideal conditions,
this is only 30 seconds, but it can be much longer if iOS is in a
low power state and is not doing any Bluetooth scanning.

Here's [a deep dive that describes how auto launching works.](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2023/06/30/background-launching)

Comment: The key thing for the OP to understand is that in order for the system to relaunch your app, you have to create one or more `CLBeaconRegion` and tell the system to start monitoring those regions. (And do all the steps you describe.) Great answer. (Voted)

Comment: What does **auto-launch** an app means? does it include the `ApplicationDelegate` methods? the root view controller? Or It's just the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `didEnterRegion` and/or `didExitRegion` ?

Comment: The most common way to launch an app on iOS is to tap on the icon in the springboard.  But there are several programmatic ways you can cause an app to be launched in the background, and a CoreLocation beacon monitoring region event change is one of these.  **Regardless of how an app is launched it always  triggers AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunching`** method.  If it was launched by a region change, then `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion` will fire after `didFinishLaunching`.   And if there is a root view, the app will attempt to start that up, too, although it will not be shown on the screen.

Comment: @davidgyoung Thanks for the detailed response. I have worked on a simple project couple of months back which uses beacon monitoring. And yes,  `didFinishLaunching` always been called along with both `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` . coming back to the project, I noticed `didFinishLaunching` is never called once phone "enters region", maybe changes in iOS or bug in the app. That was the reason of may question. Thanks!

Comment: Also worth mentioning, the monitored BLE device once disconnected, I call `[_centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil]` in `didDisconnectPeripheral` which gets connected once in region and the app re-launched.

Comment: If you do not see `didFinishLaunching` get called, yet you do see a different callback, then that means that your app has remained resident in memory (without restarting) since the last time it was called.  Effectively, it has not been launched again because it is still running from the last launch.  You can confirm this by adding a `launchTimestamp` variable to your AppDelegate, setting it in `didFinishLaunching` and logging it on other callbacks.

Comment: BTW, I wrote a blog post that does a [deep dive into the details of auto launching](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2023/06/30/background-launching).

Comment: Excellent blog post, much appreciated!